# Ajax success unable to return responds

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Am tying to update the users status on the database and if it is successful, the ajax function will display another a thankYou modal, else it should display error message. here is my code;

**matchdata.php**

```
#This a sample data that is in the db
#$matchedby = "31";
    #$matchID_Fname = "Nwabia";
    #$matchID_Lname = "Chidozie";
    #$dob = "1998-01-10";

    $matchedby = $_POST['matchID_UsersID'];
    $matchID_Fname = $_POST['matchID_Fname'];
    $matchID_Lname = $_POST['matchID_Lname'];
    $dob = $_POST['id_dob'];
    
    //$output = "0";
    //Selecting the data
    $match = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM img_upload WHERE uploadedBy='".$matchedby."' AND uploadstatus='1' ");
    
    if($match->num_rows > 0){
        #fatch data
        $result = $match->fetch_assoc();
        $rdob = $result['idDOB'];
        $rfn = $result['idFname'];
        $rln = $result['idLname'];

        #check data submitted against db
        if($matchID_Fname == $rfn && $matchID_Lname == $rln && $dob == $rdob){
            #update users status
            $updateStatus = $conn->query("UPDATE users SET users_status='5' WHERE users_id='".$matchedby."' ");    
            
            $output = "done";
            
        }
        else 
        {
            # code...
            $output = "Data do not match ID";
        }
        
    }else {
        # code...
        $output = "Unable to match data, login and try again";
    }
    
    echo $output;
```

this is where the call takes place
**index.php**

```js
function submitMatch(){
        var matchID_UsersID = document.getElementById('matchID_UsersID').value;
        var matchID_Fname = document.getElementById('matchID_Fname').value;
        var matchID_Lname = document.getElementById('matchID_Lname').value;
        var id_dob = document.getElementById('id_dob').value;
        
        //check submited inputes
        if(matchID_Fname.trim() == ''){ document.getElementById('fname_error').innerHTML = "required"; }
        else if(matchID_Lname.trim() == '') { document.getElementById('lname_error').innerHTML = "required"; }
        else if (id_dob =='') { document.getElementById('dob_error').innerHTML = "required";
        }
        else{
            //Submit data to databese using Ajax
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'matchdata.php',
                data:'submitData=1&matchID_UsersID='+matchID_UsersID+'&matchID_Fname='+matchID_Fname+'&matchID_Lname='+matchID_Lname+'&id_dob='+id_dob,
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $('#matchID_btn').attr("disabled","disabled");
                    $('.modal-body').css('opacity', '.5');
                },
                success:function(msg){
                    if(msg == "done"){
                        $('#matchdata').modal('hide');
                        $('#idVerifyThankYou').modal('show');
                    }else{
                        $('.msg').html(msg); 
                    }
                    $('#matchID_btn').removeAttr("disabled");
                    $('.modal-body').css('opacity', '1');  
                }

            });
        }
    }
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<i class='fa fa-info-circle'></i><span class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle='modal' data-target='#matchdata'>Match Data</span>
<!-- ******************* -->
<!--// Match User Data //-->
<!-- ******************* -->
<div class="modal fade" id="matchdata" role="dialog" >
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content" style="width: 60%; margin: auto">
            <div class="modal-header" >
                <h5 class="modal-title">Match Data</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" role="document">
                <div class="col-md-12 bg-primary mb-20">
                    <span><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>Match your data with that of uploaded ID.</span>
                </div>
                <span class="msg text-danger text-center"></span>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="hidden" id="matchID_UsersID" name="matchID_UsersID" value="<?php echo $aUsersID; ?>" />
                            <span id="fname_error"></span>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter first name" id="matchID_Fname" class="form-control" value="" name="matchID_Fname" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                        <span id="lname_error"></span>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter last name" id="matchID_Lname" class="form-control" value="" name="matchID_Lname" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="form-group">
                    <!--<input type="text" id="id_dob" class="form-control" value="" name="id_dob" />-->
                    <span id="dob_error"></span>
                    <input type="date" placeholder="eg: YYYY-MM-DD" id="id_dob" class="form-control" value="" name="id_dob" />
                </div>
                
                <div class="form-group text-center">
                    <input type="button" id="matchID_btn" onclick="submitMatch()" class="btn btn-primary" value="Match Data" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal Identity Verification Thank you box -->
<div class="modal fade" id="idVerifyThankYou" role="dialog" >
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content" style="width: 60%; margin: auto">
            <div class="modal-header" >
                <h5 class="modal-title">Success</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body text-center" role="document">
                <img src="../img/done.png" alt="done image">
                <div class="statusMsg col-md-12"></div>
                <div class="col-md-12 pt-10">
                    <p>Your ID has been recieved, pending approval.</p>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

if the right data is enter it updates the users database, dose not display the modal thank you modal box.

Comment: do `console.log(msg)` see what it gives you .

Comment: where do i do this console.log(msg)

Comment: Inside your `success` function and check result inside  your browsers console tab .

Comment: ok let me try it right away

Comment: its displaying done

Comment: May be you have whitespaces do `if(msg.trim() == "done"){` then add one console inside your `if` see if that gets called . Everthing else seems ok in your code.

Comment: ok let me try it right away

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Comment: thanks Swati its working now i used if(msg.trim() == "done") and its all working, but where is this whitespaces coming form

Comment: From the PHP page you return the response from. This is why it's far better practice to return the response in a serialised format, such as JSON or XML, instead of plaintext. This way the whitespace around the response becomes largely irrelevant. A plaintext response is very brittle and can be very easily broken - as you've just discovered.

Comment: thank you very much @Swati , thanks Dharman for your observation, thanks Rory McCrossan for your contributions in will work on my codes... improve more.

Answer (score 0):

THANKS TO SWATI
with Swati's support i was able to arrive at this answer.
based on the contribution of @Swati and others, it shows that the response from matachdata.php is return the output with a white space which was solved by using the trim() that Swati asked me to use.
this was the changes:

```
success:function(msg){
  if(msg.trim() == "done"{
    #some code
  }else{
   #some code
  }
```

```js
function submitMatch(){
        var matchID_UsersID = document.getElementById('matchID_UsersID').value;
        var matchID_Fname = document.getElementById('matchID_Fname').value;
        var matchID_Lname = document.getElementById('matchID_Lname').value;
        var id_dob = document.getElementById('id_dob').value;
        
        //check submited inputes
        if(matchID_Fname.trim() == ''){ document.getElementById('fname_error').innerHTML = "required"; }
        else if(matchID_Lname.trim() == '') { document.getElementById('lname_error').innerHTML = "required"; }
        else if (id_dob =='') { document.getElementById('dob_error').innerHTML = "required";
        }
        else{
            //Submit data to databese using Ajax
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'matchdata.php',
                data:'submitData=1&matchID_UsersID='+matchID_UsersID+'&matchID_Fname='+matchID_Fname+'&matchID_Lname='+matchID_Lname+'&id_dob='+id_dob,
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $('#matchID_btn').attr("disabled","disabled");
                    $('.modal-body').css('opacity', '.5');
                },
                success:function(msg){
                    if(msg.trim() == "done"){
                        $('#matchdata').modal('hide');
                        $('#idVerifyThankYou').modal('show');
                    }else{
                        $('.msg').html(msg); 
                    }
                    $('#matchID_btn').removeAttr("disabled");
                    $('.modal-body').css('opacity', '1');  
                }

            });
        }
    }
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<i class='fa fa-info-circle'></i><span class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle='modal' data-target='#matchdata'>Match Data</span>
<!-- ******************* -->
<!--// Match User Data //-->
<!-- ******************* -->
<div class="modal fade" id="matchdata" role="dialog" >
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content" style="width: 60%; margin: auto">
            <div class="modal-header" >
                <h5 class="modal-title">Match Data</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" role="document">
                <div class="col-md-12 bg-primary mb-20">
                    <span><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>Match your data with that of uploaded ID.</span>
                </div>
                <span class="msg text-danger text-center"></span>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="hidden" id="matchID_UsersID" name="matchID_UsersID" value="<?php echo $aUsersID; ?>" />
                            <span id="fname_error"></span>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter first name" id="matchID_Fname" class="form-control" value="" name="matchID_Fname" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                        <span id="lname_error"></span>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter last name" id="matchID_Lname" class="form-control" value="" name="matchID_Lname" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="form-group">
                    <!--<input type="text" id="id_dob" class="form-control" value="" name="id_dob" />-->
                    <span id="dob_error"></span>
                    <input type="date" placeholder="eg: YYYY-MM-DD" id="id_dob" class="form-control" value="" name="id_dob" />
                </div>
                
                <div class="form-group text-center">
                    <input type="button" id="matchID_btn" onclick="submitMatch()" class="btn btn-primary" value="Match Data" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal Identity Verification Thank you box -->
<div class="modal fade" id="idVerifyThankYou" role="dialog" >
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content" style="width: 60%; margin: auto">
            <div class="modal-header" >
                <h5 class="modal-title">Success</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body text-center" role="document">
                <img src="../img/done.png" alt="done image">
                <div class="statusMsg col-md-12"></div>
                <div class="col-md-12 pt-10">
                    <p>Your ID has been recieved, pending approval.</p>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```